# How does non blocking web server work?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

For example, traditional one:

```
[client] 0s GET /test  
[server] 1s got request
[server] 2s query db
[server] 3s db return 
[server] 4s return response
[client] 5s get response
```

How non-blocking web server work? for example, node?

```
                [client] 0s GET /test  
                [server] 1s got request
                /                        \
[server] 2s return response              [server] 2s query db
           |                             [server] 3s db return
           |                                      |  
           |                                      |  
           |                                      |  
[client] 3s get fake response[status]    [client] 4s get real response[data]
```

So traditional one will cost 5s and non-blocking one only 3s or 4s ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-blocking web server with request handlers that use non-blocking I/O can interleave the processing of other requests while any given request is awaiting results from non-blocking I/O requests and it can do all of this with only one thread.

So, if the first request that comes in has this sequence of events:

```
5ms [r1 - sync: receive incoming request, send read request to database]
100ms [r1 - async: read request from database returns data]
5ms [r1 - sync: convert data to proper form for the response]
5ms [r1 - async: send response back to client]
```

The operations above marked "sync:" are operations where the main thread of the non-blocking server is busy doing work.  If this non-blocking server is single threaded, then no other operations are being served at that moment.  If another request comes in during that, then it will be queued - waiting for a point where the main thread is not busy.

The first opportunity in the above sequence for a new request that is queued to be processed would be in the 100ms async database read operation.

So, let's suppose another request comes in 1ms after the above request and this time it's a write request that would have this normal progression:

```
5ms [r2 - sync: receive incoming request, send write request to database]
500ms [r2 - async: write request returns result]
5ms [r2 - async: send response back to client]
```

Then, these two requests would be interwoven:

r1 would be received, the initial processing would be done on it and then it would send it's read request off to the database.  At this point, r1 is done until the read request comes back from the database so the main server thread is now available to serve other requests.

If r2 is waiting in the queue, then the r2 request is started.  The initial processing is done on it and it sends it's write request off to the database.

At this point, there are two database operations running parallel one read from r1 and one write from r2, all from the one server thread.

Now, with these two requests both in process, the server thread has nothing to do for a little while (it could field other incoming requests if there are any).

Then, 100ms after the r1 request sent its read request, the database fires its callback to indicate that the data is available.  So, that callback starts to run and then carries out the last two steps of the r1 request and sends the response back to its client.

Then, 500ms after the r2 request sent its write request, the database fires its callback to indicate that the write operation has completed.  So that callback starts to run and then carries out the last two steps of the r2 request and send the response back to its client.

---

The operative point here is that nothing is pre-emptive.  A given request runs synchronously until it fires off an async operation.  At that point it's done with anything it can work on at that moment and the server thread is then free to serve other events waiting in its queue (other new requests coming in or other async callbacks for other requests waiting to run).  The next item is pulled from the queue and it runs until it finishes.  The next item is pulled from the queue and it runs until it finishes, etc...

---

There are a couple of advantages of non-blocking single threaded servers like node.js.

1. They can be very efficient at handling a bunch of requests in flight at the same time that do I/O.  This is because they can handle all the main processing with one thread, even though there are a bunch of request all in flight at the same time.  A non-blocking server would have to create system threads for each request in flight at the same time and this is much more resource intensive on the server-side of things and the extra overhead of multi-tasking of multiple threads also causes less efficient overall operation if you just look at the number of request/sec that a server can handle because some of the server CPU is spent doing task switching between the threads.
2. With the single thread node.js design, there are way, way fewer synchronization issues between threads because the code is all non-premptive.  Request switching from one request processing to some other request only happens at the point where a request makes a non-blocking I/O request.  This can vastly simplify lots of programming such as access to shared resources because in the node.js model, you don't have to use mutexes to guard shared data.  Not only is this significantly less code complication to write, but it's a lot less opportunity for nasty concurrency bugs.  There still can be some concurrency issues in a node.js program, but they are far fewer in number and generally simpler to code for.

There are disadvantages of the non-blocking single thread style that have to be coded around sometimes:

1. A long running synchronous calculation will "hog" the main thread and other requests won't get any cycles during that.  While it's semi-rare that there is a long running calculation that isn't also doing I/O, it can happen.  A common work-around is to move these long running calculations off into another process where it will be time sliced by the OS so the main thread can do other things.
2. Non-blocking I/O code takes some getting used to learning how to write and can be more complicated to write than blocking I/O code.  Promises are generally a big help in making this code robust, readable and easier to write (particular when processing errors).
3. If your server has multiple CPUs, a single node.js thread does not take advantage of them since it's mostly using only one CPU.  This is commonly worked around by using clustering which will run a separate node.js process for each CPU with incoming requests handed off to whichever clustered server is available.